# check if page is viewed in browser? PHP

Tags: php, curl

I was wondering if there is any way to check a page has been ran in a browser (by a human) in PHP.

I've got a page that only needs to be accessed through a cURL request. So I don't want users snooping around on it.

any ideas?

thanks

**EDIT:**

Because this is one of those questions that are not easily found on the web, here's the solution i used:

I came up with an idea thanks to anthony-arnold. Its not very stable, but it should do for now.

I simply sent the user agent in my cURL request:

```
//made a new var with the user agent string.
$user_agent = "anything I want in here, which will be my user agent";

//added this line in the cURL request to send the useragent to the target page:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
```

and then I simply wrote an if statement to handle it:

```
if 
($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == "my expected useragent - the string i previously placed into the $user_agent var."){

echo "the useragent is as expected, do whatever";
} 

else if 
($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != "my expected useragent - the string i previously placed into the $user_agent var."){

echo "useragent is not as expected, bye now."; exit();}
```

And that did the trick.

Comment: you can send special variable with cURL request

Comment: What if a human uses `curl` on the command line? :-O

Comment: That's fine, but if someone *really* want's to get access using something other than curl, they can.

Comment: Any suggestions on what I could do to make it completly secure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the `User-Agent` or use the [get browser function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) to check which browser is requesting your page. You could configure your web server to fail unless a specific user agent is specified. You can set the user agent in cURL using the `--user-agent` switch (see the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl)).

Unfortunately, the user agent can be spoofed so you can never be absolutely sure that the one sent by the client is in fact correct.

There is a problem with this idea though. If it's on the public web, you have to expect that people might try to access it in any way! If the HTTP request is valid, your server will respond to it (under default configuration). If you *really* don't want it accessed by any method other than your prescribed cURL one, then you might need to invest in some further authentication/authorization methods (e.g. username/passphrase authentication via SSL).

Comment: Just took a look at the get browser function. Do you have any idea what would be returned if the page was not viewed in a browser? I was thinking if i could just do if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == "whatever is returned when failed to get browser info"){//do something}else{//do nothing} 

Do you think that could work?

Comment: Yeah `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` would work. Just check it against the user agent you're expecting. You could ignore the `get_browser` function.